# How to draw a triangle from the number of characters entered by the user?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm trying to make a console application on .Net 6 (C#), I need the triangle to be built from the number of characters entered by the user, and not the number of LINES entered by the user.

I tried to implement a simple rendering of a triangle by timing through a nested for() loop, but my pyramid is drawn not from 6 characters, but more, from 10. I tried to implement the loop in different ways, create a new variable or add another while loop as a constant, but nothing worked.

I attached an example code below:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid: ");

    int p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the math: let's find when we can draw a triangle of `m` lines:

```
(1)     *
(2)     **
(3)     ***
...     ...
(m - 1) *** ... *
(m)     *** ... **
```

So the total number of points (`n`)

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + m = m * (m + 1) / 2 = n
```

If we solve it for `m` we will get

```
m^2 + m - 2 * n = 0

m = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * n)) / 2
```

So we can solve for `m` and if an *integer solution* exists, draw the triangle

```
private static bool DrawTriangle(int n) {
  if (n <= 0)
    return false;

  // we want integer solution (rounded), not a floating point one
  long m = (long)((-1.0 + Math.Sqrt(1.0 + 8.0 * n)) / 2.0);
        
  long residue = n - m * (m + 1) / 2;

  for (int i = 1; i <= m; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));
        
  if (residue > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', (int)residue));

  return true;
}
```

usage:

```
static void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid: ");

  // TODO: int.TryParse is a better technique
  int p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  if (!DrawTriangle(p))
    Console.WriteLine("Not a positive number");
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YflldC)

Comment: I do not dispute that your version is semantic and mathematically correct, but if the user wants to print and output 8 characters, then why not transfer these characters to the bottom line (iteration of the loop) so that the bottom lines differ by 1-2 characters?

Comment: @Jacket_Montana: OK, we can well compute `residue` (extra characters) and print them to the bottom. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The number that the user enters must be able to make a triangle. For
example, it is not possible for the number 5:

```
*
**
**
```

But if the entered number is valid, you can use the following code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid: ");
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int lineSize = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < lineSize; j++)
         {
             if(j+i<p)
                 Console.Write("*");
         }
         i = i + lineSize - 1;
         Console.WriteLine();
         lineSize++;
    }
```

**result:**

```
Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid:
5
*
**
**
Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid:
6
*
**
***
Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid:
10
*
**
***
****
Enter the number of symbols to build pyramid:
11
*
**
***
****
*
```

Comment: And is it possible in this case to implement everything in the output so that the extra characters are transferred to the next line? (in the case of the number 5)

Comment: @Jacket_Montana Yes, you can have a `Boolean flag`, if `i+j greater than p`, set the `flag to True`. If it was true, don't apply  `Console.WriteLine()`;It works fine for 5 , But this does not work for some open numbers, for example 12

Comment: @HosseinSabziani Could you add the output as formatted text (code) rather than an image of the output?

Comment: FYI, the input would look better if the prompt was written using `Write` instead of `WriteLine`

Comment: @HosseinSabziani Can you tell me exactly how to put this Boolean flag in the code?

Comment: @Jacket_Montana Just add this condition `if(i+lineSize+1 <p)` before: `Console.WriteLine();`

Comment: @phuzi I edited the answer and wrote the output as text.